# Quarkus + Vertx not performing as well as Vertx alone

Tags: vert.x, quarkus

I have 2 projects that retrieve data from the same postgres DB, running in a docker container, obtained from https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres

1 - Full Vertx -  https://github.com/lurumbo/vertx-demo

2 - Quarkus + Vertx (it is actually the Vertx project, plus some adjustments to make it work with Quarkus) - https://github.com/lurumbo/quarkus-reactive-pg-vertx-demo

I performed some stress tests on them with Jmeter and I can't wrap my head around the results

[Vertx Report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gtvCw.png)

[Quarkus Report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fypol.png)

The tests were executed with these params:

- Number of Threads (users): 1000
- Ramp-Up Period (in seconds): 0
- Loop Count: 10

What troubles me the most is the diff in the throughput values.

- Vertx: 1776.5/sec
- Quarkus: 1032.0/sec

Can you please help me understand the results?

Shouldn't the metrics be roughly the same?

Why am I getting such a diff in throughput?

Some notes:

I tested it using the runner.jar

The tests were made in JVM mode

Technical info:

- Processor Intel® Core™ i7-8565U CPU @ 1.80GHz × 8
- Memory 15,5 GiB

Thank you very much!

Comment: Are you testing with Quarkus in JVM mode or native mode?

Comment: The tests were made in JVM mode

Comment: Can you please start a thread on quarkus-dev group? SO doesn't look like the best place to discuss such things. I could spot a couple differences already: using reacting web routes in quarkus and annotated consumer

Comment: Thanks! I created a new thread in google quarkus-dev group, so here is the link 
https://groups.google.com/g/quarkus-dev/c/DimPRkZ39DM

Comment: In order for this to be answerable on Stack Overflow, you need to include the code that reproduces the performance difference *in the question itself*.